# Erro ao listar dados no Dialog do Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Ao clicar no `comandButonn` esta sendo carregado o último vídeo da lista no `dialog`, porém no `datatable` funciona corretamente quando exibo pelo componente `media`. Quero facilitar para o usuário da seguinte forma:

Quando o usuário clicar no botão `abrir` o `dialog`, exibir o vídeo do registro `X` dentro do `dialog` e clicar no segundo botão abrir o vídeo `Y`. Acho que é coisa simples, porém não estou conseguindo configurar. Estou achando estranho porque só mostra o último vídeo (Parece que não esta atualizando o `painel` no `comandButonn`. Tento `update=":mensagem :formListagem:tabela formVideo:painelVideo")`.

Segue alguns trechos do código:

Datatable (Primefaces):

```
                    <p:commandButton value="Assistir"
                        oncomplete="PF('video').show();"
                        actionListener="#{logicaAlgoritmoBean.selecionarVideo}"
                        update=":mensagem :formListagem:tabela formVideo:painelVideo" >
                        <f:attribute name="videoSelecionado" value="#{logicaAlgoritmo}" />
                    </p:commandButton>

                    <p:dialog header="Vídeo Aula" widgetVar="video"                         
                        position="top" 
                        draggable="true" resizable="true" modal="true">                         
                        <h:form id="formVideo"> 
                            <h:panelGrid id="painelVideo">                      

                                <p:outputLabel id="nomeCurso" maxlength="600" size="40"
                                value="#{logicaAlgoritmoBean.logicaAlgoritmo.curso.nomeCurso}" />

                                <p:outputLabel id="descricao" maxlength="600" size="40"
                                value="#{logicaAlgoritmoBean.logicaAlgoritmo.descricao}" />

                                <p:media cache="false" id="videos"
                                    value="http://localhost:8080/logica/#{logicaAlgoritmo.codigo}.wmv" 
                                    width="910px" 
                                    height="450px" player="windows">    
                                    <f:param name="autoPlay" value="true" />
                                    <f:param name="autostart" value="true" />                       
                                </p:media>                              

                            </h:panelGrid>
                        </h:form>                                                           
                    </p:dialog>
```

/*Aqui o componente média exibe corretamente o vídeo de cada registro.*/

```
                    <p:media cache="false" id="videos" value="http://localhost:8080/logica/#{logicaAlgoritmo.codigo}.wmv" width="200" 
                        height="150" player="windows">  
                        <f:param name="autoPlay" value="false" />
                        <f:param name="autostart" value="false" />                      
                    </p:media>
                </p:column>
```

Metodo selecionarVideo, para mostrar no console o vídeo que foi escolhido:

```
public void selecionarVideo(ActionEvent evento){
        logicaAlgoritmo = (LogicaAlgoritmo) evento.getComponent().getAttributes().get("videoSelecionado");
        System.out.println("Vídeo selecionado: "+logicaAlgoritmo);

    }
```

Metodo para lista:

```
@PostConstruct
    public void listar() {
        try {
            logicaAlgoritmoDAO logicaAlgoritmoDAO = new logicaAlgoritmoDAO();
            logicaAlgoritmos = logicaAlgoritmoDAO.listar();
        } catch (RuntimeException erro) {
            Messages.addGlobalError("Ocorreu um erro ao tentar listar a vídeo aula!");
            erro.printStackTrace();
            Messages.addGlobalError(erro.getMessage());
        }
    }
```